# Do I need to create a second Scripting.Dictionary?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that contains an employee's details, like the division and branch they are assigned to.

I'm grabbing unique branches with the code below.

```
Dim data(), dict As Object, r As Long
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

data = Sheets("Employee").UsedRange.Columns(5).Value

For r = 1 To UBound(data)
    dict(data(r, 1)) = Empty
Next

data = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys())
```

To grab the associated division that each branch belongs to (the column to the left in the table), should I create a second scripting dictionary, or is there an easier or more efficient way?

Comment: Store the "associated division" as the *value* in the dictionary (rather than leaving the value empty)? Your question is really too vague to answer. Whether or not you would want to create a second dictionary depends on what you would want to *do* with it.

Comment: Ahh, good suggestion. All I need to do is grab the division that the branch is assigned so that I can put that value in another cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store the division in the dictionary entry for that branch instead of storing an `EMPTY` value:

```
Dim data(), dict As Object, r As Long
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

data = Sheets("Employee").UsedRange.Columns(5)

For each rngCell in data
    dict(rngCell.value) = rngCell.offset(,1).value
Next

data = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys())
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here so I can't comment on the rest of the code (the transpose afterwards), but at least you have everything in the same spot.

Comment: Gotcha. I was just trying to print the all unique branches. My next line of code was Range(dataRange) = data  to print this out